# innerHTML isn't passing to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and pretty much all programming. I am attempting to make a web application and I can not seem to get innerHTML to pass to my JavaScript code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<head>
  <title>Injector Calculator
  </title>
</head>
<body type = "text/HTML/CSS">
  <p> Please enter your desired horse power!</p>
  Desired Horsepower: <input type ="text" id="desiredHp"></input>
  Which Engine: 
  <select id="engineType" type = "text" value="value">
    <option>G60T</option>
    <option>2.0 8v</option>
    <option>MK2 16v</option>
    <option>12V VR6</option>
    <option>24V VR6</option>
    <option>R32</option>
    <option>B5 S4</option>
  </select>
  <button id= "button1" onclick="computeCC();">Find my Injectors!</button>
  <p id = "output">ccs</p>
  <p id ="output2"></p>
  <script type = "text/javascript"> 
    function computeCC()
    {
        var hp = parseInt(document.getElementById("desiredHp").value);
        var eT = document.getElementById("engineType").value;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = hp;
        document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = eT;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript. JScript is something different.

Comment: There is no such thing as `type=text/HTML/CSS` on the `<body>`. Remove that. The `<input>` tag does not have a closing tag. Remove that, too.

Comment: It works fine for me, even with the mentioned invalid attribute on the body element. And applets are for Java which this is not :)

Comment: What you exactly want in your code to be solved? The function `computeCC` seems to be working fine.

Comment: Works for me, too.

Comment: A lot of times problems stem from invalid syntax, which seems to be the case here. I'm taking a guess that you're somewhat new to writing HTML code, so I'd recommend developing in a test-driven fashion until you get the hang of it by using the [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org).

Comment: I want the function to return the two inputs to the web page. This is just to test it right now. Once I get this to do what I want I will build the function to take the engine/hp input, and convert it to the appropriate BSFC and calculate which injectors are needed.

Comment: I know that the function is working because I can get it to write to a new page, but at least for me, the two user inputs are not displaying on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs little remake, you have a minor issues with syntax. select tag can't have 'value' attribute because his value is value of selected option tag and you don't need 'type' attribute for select. The input tag does not have closing tag. Your JS function fails when I enter some text that is not a number inside input tag. Here is some upgrade of your code, change something if is necessary .

```
<p> Please enter your desired horse power!</p>
Desired Horsepower: <input type ="text" id="desiredHp"/>
Which Engine: <select id="engineType">
    <option value='G60T'>G60T</option>
    <option value='2.0 8v'>2.0 8v</option>
    <option value='MK2 16v'>MK2 16v</option>
    <option value='12V VR6'>12V VR6</option>
    <option value='24V VR6'>24V VR6</option>
    <option value='R32'>R32</option>
    <option value='B5 S'>B5 S4</option>
</select>
<button id="button1" onclick="computeCC();">Find my Injectors!</button>
<p id="output"></p>
<p id="output2"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function computeCC()  {
        var hp = document.getElementById("desiredHp").value;
        if (!isNaN(hp)) {
          hp = parseInt(document.getElementById("desiredHp").value);
          var eT = document.getElementById("engineType").value;
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = hp;
          document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = eT;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add value attribute to select option element, below.

```
`<select id="engineType" type = "text">
        <option value="G60T">G60T</option>
        <option value="2.0 8v">2.0 8v</option>
        <option value="MK2 16v">MK2 16v</option>
        <option value="12V VR6">12V VR6</option>
        <option value="24V VR6">24V VR6</option>
        <option value="R32">R32</option>
        <option value="B5 S4">B5 S4</option>
    </select>`
```

Answer (score 0):

- there is no `type = "text/HTML/CSS"`
- `<option>` needs value
- get selected value with `el.options[el.selectedIndex].text`

**In total**

```js
function output() {
  var horsepower = document.getElementById("horsepower"),
    outputHorsepower = document.getElementById("outputHorsepower"),
    engine = document.getElementById("engine"),
    outputEngine = document.getElementById("outputEngine");

  outputHorsepower.innerHTML = horsepower.value;
  outputEngine.innerHTML = engine.options[engine.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<p> Please enter your desired horse power!</p>
<div>
  <label>Desired Horsepower: </label>
  <input type="text" id="horsepower" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Which Engine:</label>
  <select id="engine" type="text">
        <option value="G60T">G60T</option>
        <option value="2.0 8v">2.0 8v</option>
        <option value="MK2 16v">MK2 16v</option>
        <option value="12V VR6">12V VR6</option>
        <option value="24V VR6">24V VR6</option>
        <option value="R32">R32</option>
        <option value="B5 S4">B5 S4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="button" onclick="output();">Find my Injectors!</button>
<div id="outputHorsepower"></div>
<div id="outputEngine"></div>
```